# Align checkbox with text inside a td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question is answered several times but I can't seems find a post that is not using `<label>` as label for their checkbox

I want to align the text and checkbox inside a `<td>` without using a `<label>`. Here is my table structure

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> test </th>
            <th> beng </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> broom </td>
            <td class="tdClass">
                <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="benefits"> test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I tried using CSS to align them

```
td.test {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uT4Sb/)

also if it is related I'm using bootstrap

Comment: Assuming you are having troubles getting it *vertically* aligned? It looks pretty good in FF and Chrome - is there a particular browser that's giving you issues?

Comment: You would need to wrap the element if you want it vertically aligned more precisely. Why don't you want to use a `label`? Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/AXZr4/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I was about to comment that

Comment: @JoshCrozier I'm using datatables, I avoid as much as possible any component inside a `td` but in this case I really need a checkbox. Any element inside a `td` interferes with the search function of the tables because it includes the component when you use the search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uT4Sb/1/)